# Где решать задачи и практиковаться в кодинге на питоне и шарпе?

Tags: python, c#

Подскажите, пожалуйста, ресурсы(желательно бесплатные), где можно так сказать набивать руку, решать задачи, практиковаться в кодинге. На питоне и шарпе.

Answer (score 1):

Кодворз, хакеранк, ЧЕКЙО.ОРГ.  В основном алгоритмические задачи

Comment: Пожалуйста, подобное помещайте в комментарии. Это субъективное мнение без доказательств.

Comment: Какие нужны доказательства для этого ответа?
Хороший ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Сайт [acmp.ru](https://acmp.ru) - олимпиадные задачки по многим языкам, в том числе Python и C#.